# Сказуемое безличного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

В одном из старых, но уважаемых мною учебников читаю примеры безличных предложений: "Герасима не было на дворе", "У меня нет отца". При этом сказуемыми отмечены соответственно "Герасима не было", "нет отца". А затем посмотрел самый авторитетный сборник тестов для ГИА-2013 под ред. И.Цибулько и прочитал: "Этого диагноза у Игнатия нет". Ответ на вопрос о грамматической основе данного предложения обозначен однозначно: "нет". Так как же все-таки правильно? Считаю, что грамматическая основа предложения должна заключать в себе и зерно мысли. Но какое "зерно" в слове "нет"?

Comment: В слове "нет" заключается отсутствие чего-либо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, современный синтаксис более логичен.(Вернее, не современный, а академический. Вы привели пример позиции некоторых учёных прошлых лет, но грамматика развивается, по-моему, они тоже признали правоту академических грамматик.) У меня есть отец.-Кто?-отец.Что о нём говорится?-что он есть( в наличии)У меня нет отца. - отрицается субъект, он переходит в положение объекта - дополнения.Безличное отрицательное предложение используется для указания на недостаток или отсутствие кого или чего-нибудь. Слово "нет" как раз и указывает на отсутствие - всё, что требуется от сказуемого безличного предложения.

На улице жарко. На улице будет жарко. На улице не было жарко. - Смысл информации в слове "жарко", а не было - лишь вспомогательный глагол составного именного сказуемого. Герасима не было на дворе.- Предложение информирует об отсутствии. Кого? Герасима - дополнение.Где?-на дворе - обстоятельство. Всё логично.

Comment: Извините, если не смогу ответить на комментарии : уезжаю на 3 дня.

Answer (score 4):

Да, сказуемым являются слова "нет", "не было". Дети делают ошибку, обозначая слова "отца", "Герасима" как подлежащее.  ***Отец **у него** был***. Подлежащее отец, был (существовал) - сказуемое. *Отца  у него **не было***. Сказуемое "не было". Отца - дополнение, т.к. падеж косвенный.

Comment: @Ларf: "Дети делают ошибку, обозначая слова "отца", "Герасима" как подлежащее". Я бы  не стала считать это ошибкой. Скорее всего, допустила бы оба варианта. Может, я и не права.

Comment: >Отец у него был. Подлежащее отец, был (существовал) - сказуемое. 
  

Не факт. Скорее уж "был отец" и "не было отца" - составные сказуемые. По крайней мере некоторая логичность в таком кдинообразии просматривается.

Answer (score 2):

**Сегодня будет жарко.**  *Будет* сказуемое, *жарко* обстоятельство?
Мне как-то вариант Виктора больше по душе.
И что современные учебники  считают составным сказуемым?

Comment: Нет, в Вашем предложении сказуемое "будет жарко". Жарко. Будет жарко. Было жарко. - Односоставные безличные нераспространенные предложения. Нам многое может не нравиться. Но приходится подчиняться принятой систематике. Составным сказуемым называется то же, что и раньше. Т.е. сказуемое, в котором лексическое и грамматическое значение выражено разными словами.

Comment: Лариса, поясните, пожалуйста.Если "будет жарко" - сказуемое безличного предложения, значит, "не было жарко" - тоже сказуемое. Почему же тогда в предложении "Герасима не было на дворе" сказуемое только "не  было"

Comment: Извините. не видела вовремя комментария. По-моему. Людмила понятно объяснила.

Answer (score 0):

Где-то тут что-то нехорошее зарыто. Чувствую, но обосновать не могу.

*Жарко в августе не было*.
*Жары в августе не было*.

Подлежащее - это, вроде бы, то, о чём (о ком) говорится в предложении. О ком говорится в предложении "Герасима не было во дворе"? Может быть, дети не так уж неправы?

Comment: "Нехорошее" в том, что это односоставное безличное предложение, в котором нет  и быть не может подлежащего(лица, совершающего действие). Зачем же его искать? Вся основная информация в сказуемом "не было жарко". Разве не понятно, что это происходит само, без какого-либо лица? По-моему, Вы полезли в дебри.

Comment: По-моему, это очевидно (про дебри). Вы не чувствуете, какое тут тонкое место (как трещит структурная схема)?

Почему в предложении "*Жарко в августе не было*" сказуемое "не было жарко", а в предложении "*Жары в августе не было*" сказуемое только "не было"? Или я ошибаюсь?..

Comment: Да не ошибаетесь. Просто мы (я и Людмила) говорим о принятых на сегодняшний день грамматических канонах. И не раз говорили о том, что трудно уложить язык в прокрустово ложе схем и правил.